# "Invalid projection" when creating a CRS

Tags: python, gis, proj, pyproj

I am attempting to construct a CRS instance with PyProj to match a geographic shape to image bounds. With the following code

```
pyproj.Proj(proj='aea', lat1=b[1], lat2=b[3])
```

I am getting the error:

```
pyproj.exceptions.CRSError: Invalid projection: +proj=aea
 +lat1=34.82176739999999 +lat2=34.8219931 +type=crs
```

There doesn't seem to be a lot of documentation about what makes a projection valid or invalid, apart from an apparently [no longer extant documentation page](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/wiki/GenParms) on the Proj4 wiki. Can anyone help me to understand what's going wrong here? The code (not written by me) appears to have worked in the past.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue here is you mispelled the projection parameters.

*lat1* and *lat2* should be *lat_1* and *lat_2* (with the underscore).

The correct proj string should be:

`+proj=aea +lat_1=34.82176739999999 +lat_2=34.8219931`

You can find more details about the format of the proj string in the official documentation, linked here: https://proj4.org/operations/projections/aea.html